# Problem with data binging and Facebook LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook, data-binding

i want to use Facebook LoginButton widget with data binding.

This is my layout:

> view_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
                name="model"
                type="com.example.login.LoginScreenVM"/>
    </data>

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</layout>
```

When i try to run my app i get this error:

> ViewLoginBinding.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
>     public final LoginButton loginButton;

Edit:

I use this to bind view:

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.view_login);
```

In gradle i have:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Nothing fancy.

When i put this widget in plain layout (witout  tag, separate file) and delete it from view_login i can run app.

Comment: add   implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0' in your gradle

Comment: It is already added.

Comment: pls add your java code

Comment: Problem description updated.